# Devexpress Aspxgridview Callback

Tags: callback, devexpress, aspxgridview

Hi guys i have a problem.

Im making a callback from an aspxgridview. I do callback when i make RowDblClick and then i switch to another tab of the pageControl and fill some controls with database information. One of those controls is another gridview. So what i want to do is when i rowdblclick in the new gridview, make another callback.

I dont know why but when i double click the new aspxgridview, my application stacks. So i haven't response of the callback.  I stopped the first callback of the first grid, and the second callback works fine.

So my question is, how can i make a callback in an aspxgridview by a rowdblclick, and after that make another callback with another rowdblclick in another aspxgridview?

this is first aspxgridview

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grillaInformes" runat="server" KeyFieldName="ID" width="100%"        EnableCallBacks="false" ClientInstanceName="grillaInformes" OnCustomCallback="grillaInformes_CustomCallback">
                    <ClientSideEvents RowDblClick="function(s, e) { s.PerformCallback(e.visibleIndex); }"/>
```

and this is the second aspxgridview, whose callback doesn't work because i made another callback before of grillaInformes

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grillaSubInformes" runat="server" KeyFieldName="ID"  Width="100%" EnableCallBacks="false" ClientInstanceName="grillaSubInformes" OnCustomCallback="grillaSubInformes_CustomCallback"  >
                       <ClientSideEvents RowDblClick="function(s, e) { s.PerformCallback(e.visibleIndex); }"/>
```

Comment: Why do you set EnableCallBacks to false in both grids? Have you tried setting breakpoint in customcallback handler? Does app enter that method? Do you get any javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling a defined JavaScript function for the CallBacks, and stepping through the code there? For example:

```
function grillaInformes_RowDblClick(s, e) {
    s.PerformCallback(e.visibleIndex);
}

function grillaSubInformes_RowDblClick(s, e) {
    s.PerformCallback(e.visibleIndex);
}
```

and use the following for your grid:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grillaInformes" runat="server" KeyFieldName="ID" width="100%" EnableCallBacks="false" ClientInstanceName="grillaInformes" OnCustomCallback="grillaInformes_CustomCallback">
                    <ClientSideEvents RowDblClick="grillaInformes_RowDblClick"/>

<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grillaSubInformes" runat="server" KeyFieldName="ID"  Width="100%" EnableCallBacks="false" ClientInstanceName="grillaSubInformes" OnCustomCallback="grillaSubInformes_CustomCallback"  >
                       <ClientSideEvents RowDblClick="grillaSubInformes_RowDblClick"/>
```

You should see right away whether the second double-click is even starting, then step through the code behind. We do things like this often though, and have no problem with multiple callbacks running at one time.

Comment: i solved this by putting a timer of 10 miliseconds after i make the double click.

Comment: If you truly solved your own problem then you may wanna write it up as an answer and mark it as the answer.